# How to call a custom function of Azure Mobile Service from Cordova mobile app?

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am developing a Cordova-Ionic App with Azure Mobile Service(.Net) as backend.
I want to call a function that is written in Service. e.g an email want to send from the service when user press a button in mobile app. So the function to send email is written in Service. How to call the function from the Cordova App?
Can anybody help please

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom API on the server and call it using `invokeAPi` in the client SDK:

- [How to: Define a custom API controller](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller)
- [Calling custom APIs in Cordova](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/16/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-21-calling-custom-apis/)